# how to add a youtube video in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a Youtube video in my flutter web  app , I tried Youtube_player_iframe and its not showing anything ..
here is my code :

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
      _controller = YoutubePlayerController(

        params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
          showControls: true,
          mute: false,
          showFullscreenButton: true,
          loop: false,
        ),
      )..onInit = (){
        _controller.loadVideoByUrl(mediaContentUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oZXNRQ0_Uo');
      };
  }
in the scaffold : 
 YoutubePlayerControllerProvider(controller: _controller, child: YoutubePlayer(
                    aspectRatio: 4/3,
                    controller: _controller,
                  )),
```

Comment: Everything seems fine except that the docs on the package's homepage suggests using a builder which returns the player instead of the `YoutubePlayer`. Why not try that first?

Comment: can you give me an example please ?

Comment: ```
YoutubePlayerScaffold( controller: _controller,  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget player) {
                    return Scaffold(
                      body: player,
                    );
```

Comment: i tried this and it gives an ( error Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out)

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution just replace the

```
_controller.loadVideoByUrl(...);
```

to

```
_controller.loadVideo(...);
```